# Circular progress bar with percentage in Android with use of minimum code

Tags: android, android-layout, progress-bar, android-custom-view, androiddesignsupport

[image: Show progress of task status]

Have you any idea how to make a circular progress bar that show progress with percentage?

Comment: You need to draw the custom view to do this.